# data structure for accessing sorted subsets of a set c++

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, dictionary, set

I have a set of values `V` that are accessed by their indecies `I` -- that is `i->V[i]`.
I need to iterate over these according to the values `V[i]` (e.g. from large to small).
Furthermore I have subsets of the original indecies `I_1, I2,..., I_N` and I need to access their corresponding values in the same order (from large to small).

What is the right data-structure and procedure to use here? I've been struggling with this for some time so any help is appreciated.

Note that the values (`V[i]`) are constantly updated and access is always through the indices `i`. 
If I was using the a `set` to represent the values then I would need to remove the updated element and insert it back with the hint as where to put it (very likely it is close to its previous location in the set). But a set would only contain `V`, and does not allow me to access the elements through i. On the other hand using `Map` or `Multimap` elements are sorted by `I` rather than `V`.

It seems that I need to use a combination of pointers and sets etc. but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you need a combination. Here's what I would do:

```
std::map<SomeKey, SomeObject> sortedObjects;
std::vector<std::map<SomeKey, SomeObject>::iterator> indexedObjects;
```

Insert an object:

```
indexedObjects.push_back(sortedObjects.emplace(newKey, newObject).first);
```

The idea here is that the objects are *actually* in a `map` but a `vector` which can be accessed by index holds `iterator`s to the objects in the map. The key thing is that neither container is modified unless both are. You could write a class that wraps these 2 containers together such that you *can't* modify one without modifying the other, or you could just make sure you never make that mistake.

Access the elements by index from `indexedObjects` and by key from `sortedObjects`. If you need to add/remove elements from middle indices use a `list` instead of a `vector`, so you can add/remove from the middle of the container. If you don't have a separate key, use a `set`, not a `map`. If you have duplicate keys/objects use a `multiset` or `multimap`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm a bit confused about the mapping between your notation and mine. Does your `SomeKey` correspond to my indices or values? Because if they are indices then they are sorted by index rather than the value and if they are the value `V[i]` then what are the objects (`SomeObjects`)? But Lets say instead of `map` we use `set` containing values `V`--as you suggested. In that case what happens to indices?

Comment: @Siamak The indices are implied by the fact that indexedObjects[index] gives you an iterator to an object. As far as your confusion with `SomeKey` - look up `std:map`. No, it would not be your index - it would be the attribute you want your objects sorted on.

Comment: since I'm sorting by the values `V`, there would be no need for a `map` but rather a `set` (`std::set<SomeObject>`) which I would access using the `indexedObjects`. But this does not allow me to iterate over a subset of values (indexed by a subset of indexedObject) in a sorted order. right? Even to iterate over the `set` of values I would not be able to use the `indexedObject` (for that I could iterate over the `set` itself).